# JQuery Mobile Multipage & Appended footer has no styling (Intel XDK)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, intel-xdk

The multipage is working, but I want to inject the footer code in every page container.
Page Code:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <div class="upage" id="mainpage" data-role="page">
     <div class="upage-outer">
       <!-- some content -->
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="upage" id="uberpage" data-role="page">
     <div class="upage-outer">
       <!-- some content -->
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the I just inject the footer code with some buttons (When device is ready):

```
$(".upage-outer").append('<div data-role="footer">Copyright + Buttons</div>');
```

This is the full footer code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_4" data-uib="jquery_mobile/footer" data-ver="0">
                        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="brideButtonGroup">
                            <a class="widget uib_w_6" data-role="button" href="#mainpage" rel="external">Wetter</a>
                            <a class="widget uib_w_7" data-role="button" onclick="intel.xdk.device.launchExternal('http://wetter2.mt-labor.it.hs-worms.de/plot');">Mehr</a>
                            <a class="widget uib_w_8" data-role="button" href="#uberpage" rel="external">Über</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The code gets injected, but on the mainpage, the Buttons are not displayed; instead, there are plain text links. On the second page, everything is displayed very well. I can switch between the pages.

What did I do wrong?

edit: I used enhanceWhithin(), and its working. But when I click somewhere on the document, strange colors appear, which are caused by the class ".ui-fixed-hidden". Where does this come from?

edit2: https://jsfiddle.net/564f1fkf/ It's not exactly the same, but if you go to site 2 and then back to site 1 and click somewhere on the page, you should see the problem.

PS: See pictures

[image: What it looks like]

[image: Like it should be]

Comment: Try using the enhanceWithin() method

Comment: @TinoMThomas this is almost working. The style is ok, but the colors are wrong. [This is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/XDPeSgZ.png)

Comment: can you post your footer's html code also?

Comment: @TinoMThomas I edited my question

Comment: is it possible to create a jsfiddle for us to investigate? and one more thing make sure that you call the enhanceWithin() method on the 'data-role="page" element

Comment: @TinoMThomas Yes added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/564f1fkf/) in the question

Comment: I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/564f1fkf/1/.), Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked very well. Just post this as answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: done..You are welcome.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the `enhanceWithin()` method on `data-role="content"` element. This will enhance the newly added HTML into jQuery mobile format.

```
$("[data-role='content']").enhanceWithin();
```